# Flow analysis and user flow

Tags: user-research, ux-designer, flow

What is the difference between flow analysis and user flow?
Is there any difference or are these terms exchangeable?

Comment: Although I could see it being used, I'm not too sure what 'flow analysis' means with relation to UX. Could you share where have you seen the term?

Comment: A similar question that you might also want to reference: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45405/what-are-the-differences-between-user-flows-task-flows-and-workflows

Answer (score 1):

user flow would be mapping out an existing or desired flow the user goes through when using a product or service, similar to an experience map.

I've never heard of 'flow analysis' but i'm guessing it would be the action of analysing the user flow. Probably with analysis tools such an google analytics, finding the points where the flow is broken and  providing solutions on how to improve the flow for instance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there -

I'd say, without much more information, that 'user flow' can apply to both a 'current' and 'desired' or 'intended' user flow you're mapping out. 'Flow analysis', on the other hand, specifically implies an existing flow.

In short, if you're being asked to do both by someone, they could well be asking you to 'examine the current flow' (flow analysis) and then 'design one in response to the problems with that' (user flow 'designing').